# Why do I get both positions x and y to be 0 in the response of tensorflow.js posenet?

Tags: tensorflow.js

Initialization of posenet

```
const net = await posenet.load();

const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(videoElement, {
  flipHorizontal: false
});
```

Output

```
part: "leftEye"
position: {x: 0, y: 0}
score: 0.9931495785713196
```

My question is I always get position 0,0 for every body parts even though the score is high.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Make sure you add width and height to source element (image or video). Notice that if you add width and height from css it will not work, you need to add it programmatically.

```
 video = document.getElementById("video");

 //must add the following
 video.width = 500;
 video.height = 500;
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Thank you for the solution.